# How do I use the ifelse function for multiple values?

Tags: r, if-statement

```
credit$EDUCATION <- as.factor(ifelse(credit$EDUCATION == 1, 2, 3, 4, "Graduate_School", "College", "High_School", "Other", "Unknown"))
```

1 "Graduate_School",
2 "College",
3 "High_School",
4 "Other",
Everything else that is not values 1 through 4 becomes Unknown

Answer (score 2):

If we have numeric index, use that for replacement

```
credit$EDUCATION <- c("Graduate_School", "College", "High_School", "Other")[credit$EDUCATION]
credit$EDUCATION[is.na(credit$EDUCATION)] <- "Unknown"
```